# Difference Between Cognito User Pool and API Key For API Auth Type

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm currently setting up AWS Amplify with my react app and adding an API so I can use GraphQL.
I'm currently at a choice to add authorization type and my two options are API key or Amazon cognito user pool.
It's my understanding that the second choice means if a user is signed in, they can interact with the API calls.
What does the first choice (API key) mean?
What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

API key is basically for unauthenticated workflows where the app doesn't need private access for different users. User Pools allows you to apply fine grained access controls. Take a look at the options with @auth in the GraphQL Transformer: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#auth

Answer (score 0):

API key is for public datas and Cognito user pools for private datas.
A good link :
https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify